# How to join a same table with two tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create an Oracle database view :

```
create or replace force view view_ind_pta (indi_code, nat_indi_code, indi_unite, indi_symbole, indi_lib, indi_cible, pta_intitule, indi_resp, 
indi_source_info, user_code, peri_mes_code, peri_mes_lib, pta_parent, deleted,obj_intitule,pta_action) 
as 
select distinct
i.indi_code,
i.nat_indi_code,
i.indi_unite,
i.indi_symbole,
to_char(i.indi_lib) as indi_lib,
i.indi_cible,
concat(concat(to_char(a.pta_ref),' - '),to_char(a.pta_intitule)) as pta_intitule,
i.indi_resp,
to_char(i.indi_source_info) as indi_source_info,
u.user_code,
i.peri_mes_code , 
pm.peri_mes_lib ,
concat(concat(to_char(p.pta_ref),' - '),to_char(p.pta_intitule)) as pta_parent,
i.deleted ,
to_char(o.obj_intitule) as obj_intitule,
concat(concat(to_char(action.pta_ref),' - '),to_char(action.pta_intitule)) as pta_action
from
indicateur i
left join acteur_saisie_indicateur ai on ai.indi_code = i.indi_code
left join acteur_verif_indicateur avi on avi.indi_code = i.indi_code
left join utilisateur u on ( ai.user_code = u.user_code and avi.user_code = u.user_code) 
left join objectif o on i.obj_code = o.obj_code
left join pta a on o.pta_code = a.pta_code
left join pta action on a.pta_pta_code = action.pta_code
left join pta p on action.pta_pta_code = p.pta_code 
left join periodicite_mesure pm on pm.peri_mes_code = i.peri_mes_code
where p.pta_definitif = 3;
```

In the view there is the table **utilisateur** which I want to join with the two tables **acteur_saisie_indicateur** and **acteur_verif_indicateur**. I tried the `and` operator , but I think it is not a good idea because the query will return rows only when there are joined rows in both tables ! Although this is not necessary : I want the query to return rows even if only one table has joined rows. So how to join these three tables ?

Comment: Start with reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: That's a lot of outer joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can include the same table in a FROM clause more than once. All we need to do is use different aliases to distinguish the instances:

```
left join utilisateur uai 
    on ai.user_code = uai.user_code
left join utilisateur uavi 
    on avi.user_code = uavi.user_code
```

The other thing you need to do is handle table's columns in the view's projection. You want to display the `utilisateur` values regardless of which instance the values come from, say by using `nvl()` or the industry standard `coalesce()`

```
coalesce(uai.user_code, uavi.user_code) as user_code
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the table twice:

```
left join acteur_saisie_indicateur ai on ai.indi_code = i.indi_code
left join acteur_verif_indicateur avi on avi.indi_code = i.indi_code
left join utilisateur u on ai.user_code = u.user_code 
left join utilisateur u2 on avi.user_code = u2.user_code
```